# Preserve style after animation players - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with a couple buttons and text in it.  You can click these buttons and if the conditions are met, I have a fading color animation plays accross the entire DataGrid Row indicating that the event was successful, as well as one for when a failure state occured:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="AnimationSuccessful">
    <ColorAnimation To="#22218ffe" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                    FillBehavior="HoldEnd" 
                    Duration="0:0:0.3" />
</Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Key="AnimationUnsuccessful">
    <ColorAnimation To="#00fe1f21" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                    FillBehavior="HoldEnd" 
                    Duration="0:0:0.6"/>
</Storyboard>
```

Also on this DataGrid is a generic DataGridRow Style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" x:Key="DefaultDataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource FG_Gray}"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BG_HL_Gray}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BG_Selected_Gray}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

All this works, except...

When you click a button and the 'Successful' or 'Unsuccessful' animation plays, the baseline style never works again.

After doing some searching on how to address this problem, I think I've settled on trying to hook up the Animations as EventTriggers to the baseline style.  However, I'm not really sure how to address the specific row I want to play the animation on at Run Time with a custom RoutedEvent.

Is this the correct approach, or is there a better way to 'restore' my style after the event plays?

Comment: Why are you targeting `(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)` instead of just `(Button.Background)`? I'm not 100% sure but I wouldn't try to change the color property there. How do you activate your storyboards?

Comment: Set the `FillBehavior` property to `Stop` instead of `HoldEnd`?